# csshover.htc and cakephp

Tags: cakephp, internet-explorer-6, hover

I tried using the script csshover.htc to solve the problem of hover in ie6 but unfortunately when I add this code

`body {behavior: url ('csshover.htc');}`

CakePHP makes me a false path to the file.

csshover.htc file is in the same folder as the css file so in app/webroot/css/

if anyone has encountered the same problem as me thank you for helping me

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try referencing the behaviour with the full path:

```
body {
  behavior: url ('/css/csshover.htc');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I have used the full path but no result